# HTML5 video in fast forward - require complete download?

Tags: html, html5-video

Does html5 video fast-forward via `playbackRate` require all of the video to be loaded in or does the player request the frames it needs from the server?

Answer (score 0):

The player requests the part needed from the server much like Youtube